# how can convert a 2d numpy array to an array of pointers in cython, without using memoryviews

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Using memoryviews for my 1d arrays seems to be significantly slower than using a raw pointer. Is there an easy way to convert a multidimensional numpy array (or memoryview) to an array of pointers?

This is what I do for 1d arrays:

```
cdef np.ndarray[dtype=double, ndim=1] a1
cdef double* a2 = &a1[0]
```

I need something for a 3d array:

```
cdef np.ndarray[dtype=double, ndim=3] b1
cdef double*** b2 = <something here>
```

Obviously I can flatten the 3d array and compute the necessary 1d indices.

I could also manually fill the  `double*** b2` arrays:

```
    b2 = <double ***> malloc(len(b1) * sizeof(double**))
    for i, a in enumerate(b1):
        b2[i] = <double **> malloc(len(a) * sizeof(double*))
        for j, b in enumerate(a):
            b2[i][j] = <double *> malloc(len(b) * sizeof(double))
            for k, c in enumerate(b):
                b2[i][j][k] = c
```

But is there a better built-in way to do that?

Comment: Before you do this, have you turned off things like boundschecking and negative indexing (once you've verified that it's safe/makes sense)? This can make memoryviews significantly faster. I also suspect that any speedups you see for 1D arrays might disappear given three layers of indirection (but I could be wrong)

Comment: AFAIK, Numpy array can have a stride, even in 1D. I think you should consider this case. A good example is a transposed 2D array.

Comment: Yeah, I do have boundschecking and wraparound off. There's no striding (I have control of the inputs).

Comment: Ok, good. By the way, what do you mean by "better"? Do you mean faster or simpler? Additionally, may I ask you why do you want to convert a Numpy array into a jagged array? Jagged arrays are known to be very inefficient and take more space in memory.

Comment: Better is less cumbersome code, but the same speed. All of the indications are that the memoryview should be as fast or faster, but I just didn't find that to be the case.